# Heat Flow Equation Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm currently working on a project to build a solar food dryer and I need to model on Matlab how temperature of the product will change with respect to change in solar radiation, Q .

Q is given by ;

```
Q =960*(sin(2*pi*Time2/24)).^2; %W/m2
```

where

```
Time2 = (1:t:12); %hours
```

The heat flow equation is given by

```
Q(t)A = mcp*(T2-T1) + (mw*lw)
```

where :

```
mw = 0.706; % Mass of water loss from product in hr (Kg/h)

m = 15; % Mass of product to dry (Kg)

lw = 2260000; % Latent heat of vaporisation of water (J/Kg)

A = 1; % Surface Area of collector (m^2)

cp= 3746; % Specific heat capacity of product (J/Kg/C)

T1 = temperature at t

T2 = temperature at t + dt
```

Manipulating the heat flow give T2 as ;

```
T2= (((Q*A*3600) -(mw*lw))/(m*cp)) + T1; % 3600 is there to convert j/s to J/h
```

however implementing this on Matlab is proving a challenge for me- I'm fairly new to Matlab

This is what I have so far ;

```
close all

clear;

mw = 0.706; % Mass of water loss from product in hr (Kg/h)

m = 15; % Mass of product to dry (Kg)

lw = 2260000; % Latent heat of vaporisation of water (J/Kg)

A = 1; % Surface Area of Collector (m^2)

cp= 3746; % Specific heat capacity of product (J/Kg/C)

t = 1; % Time step

T = 24; % Initial Temperature (°C)



Time2=(1:t:12); hours

Q=960*(sin(2*pi*Time2/24)).^2; % Solar irradiation in tropical regions at specific time (W/m2)

for j = 1:12

 T(j+1)= ((((QQ2(j)*A*j*3600))-(mw*lw))/(m*cp))+ T(1);

end

figure(2)

plot(T)

title('Temperature')

xlabel('time (hours)')

ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
```

This seems wrong since the mass, m should decrease by mw after each hr and the temperature profile should follow the profile of the solar radiation. i.e peak at the same time

I have been spending days to get my head around this but i'm pretty bad at Matlab so I haven't made any meaningful progress. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if this is what you are looking for Ran, but there are a few points that looked like typos (?) and these would change behaviour. You have `QQ2(j)` suddenly appears in the middle of your script... I presumed that was just Q[j). Each cycle of your loop you add to t(1) and I think you meant t(j)? And surely the loop should also decrease the m?
So I modified to this...

```
for j = 1:12
     T(j+1)= ((((Q(j)*A*j*3600))-(mw*lw))/(m*cp))+  T(j);
     m=m-mw*t;
end
```

Now T peaks at 12noon.

All that said, I would think a problem like this would be better solved with a differential equation solver like ‘ode45()’, but I would need to see that differential equation before advising how to do that in Matlab, but it shouldn’t be too tricky!

### Hello again Ran, OK you have added the dydx in the the comments now so here is how I would approach this problem, (accepting I don’t know much about this equation itself!):

```
 clear;
global conv;
conv=60*60;
mw = 0.706/conv; % Mass of water loss from product in hr (Kg/h)
m = 15.0; % Mass of product to dry (Kg)
lw = 2260000.0; % Latent heat of vaporisation of water (J/Kg)
A= 1.0; % Surface Area of Collector (m^2)
cp= 3746.0; % Specific heat capacity of product (J/Kg/C)
T = 24.0; % Initial Temperature (°C)
%%
%% for j = 1:12
%% T(j+1)= ((((Q(j)*A*j*3600))-(mw*lw))/(m*cp))+ T(j);
%% m=m-mw*t;
%% end

tspan = [0, 12*conv];
yo=[T;m];
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) ode(t, y,[A,mw,lw,cp]), tspan, yo);

yfinal=y;
figure (1)
plot(t./conv,yfinal(:,1))
title('Temperature')
xlabel('time (hours)')
ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
figure (2)
tqs=linspace(0,12);
Qt=960.0*(sin(2.0.*pi.*tqs./(24.0))).^2;
plot(tqs,Qt);
function dydt=ode(t,y,x)
    global conv;
    A =x(1);
    mw =x(2);
    lw =x(3);
    cp =x(4);
    m=y(2);
    Q=960*(sin(2*pi*t/(24*conv)))^2; % Solar irradiation in tropical regions at specific time (W/m2)
    dydt=[((Q * A)-(mw*lw))/(m*cp);-mw];
end
```

This gives this output, I think the equations will need a fiddle, but hopefully the structure of the ODE helps?
P.s., I am not convinced that peak temperature would match peak heat input since usually there is a lag.  Hottest part of the day is often 3pm in the UK... but I haven’t looked at heat transfer since High School...
 [image: THIS]

Regards R

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for the reply. Indeed the QQ2(j) and T(1) were meant to be Q(j) and T(i) . On the graph, I was expecting the profile of the temperature to be directly proportional to the solar radiation, so any time the the solar radiation decrease, the temperature should decrease and they should peak at the same time i.e. the sixth hour. In terms of differential equation, the equation will be                 
 dT/dt = ((Q * A)-(mw* lw))/(m*cp)); and T0, initial temperature = 24 . Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that differential equation now and the ODE45 function. I hope this helps.